# I can't use the json response for displaying dynamic pie chart using canvas.min.js and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html5-canvas, httpresponse, pie-chart

I'm returning data in exact form as required by datapoints in pie chart(scope.myData same data as in scope.s)....but the values are not displayed in pie chart...but if i give same json format in var and assign it to datapoints its working fine(scope.s)...I don't understand why??

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html data-ng-app="myapp">
    <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>AngularJS Tutorial</title>
    <script 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js">
   </script>
   <script>
  var app = angular.module('myapp',[ ]);

  app.controller('HelloWorldController', function($scope, $http){
     var res = $http.get('http://localhost:8088/api/user/');
    res.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.myData = data;
    });
    res.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert( "failure message: " + JSON.stringify({data: data}));
    }); 
    $scope.s=  [{"y":1,"legendText":"DB 
      check","label":"DB","color":"green"},{"y":1,"legendText":"F 
        check","label":"Folder","color":"red"}]

    $scope.chart1 = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
            {
                title:{
                    text: "Statistics of health check "
                },
                        animationEnabled: true,
                legend:{
                    verticalAlign: "center",
                    horizontalAlign: "left",
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontFamily: "Helvetica"        
                },
                theme: "theme2",
                data: [
                {        
                    type: "pie",       
                    indexLabelFontFamily: "Garamond",       
                    indexLabelFontSize: 20,

                    indexLabel: "{label} {y}%",
                    startAngle:-20,      
                    showInLegend: true,
                    toolTipContent:"{legendText} {y}%",
                    dataPoints:$scope.myData //This is where problem lies
                }
                ]
            });
            $scope.chart1.render();       
     });
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript" 
 src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script> 

 </head>
 <body data-ng-controller="HelloWorldController">

  <h1>You selected: 

  {{myData}}
   </h1>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>

 </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: can you do console log of `$scope.myData` & check what is its output?

Comment: Seems like you are getting the API response after chart. can you put console.log for myData.

Comment: Its printing undefined for console.log

Comment: Its printing undefined for console.log($scope.myData)...but its printing exact format when i use {{myData}} @AgamBanga

Answer (score 0):

You created explicit object and passed to `new CanvasJS.Chart`.

Don't use `myData`, update all chart options and re-render:

A.e.: `$scope.chart1 = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",$scope.options);`

and (dummy data):

```
$scope.options.data[0].dataPoints  = [
                { label: "apple",  y: 10  },
                { label: "orange", y: 15  },
                { label: "banana", y: 25  },
                { label: "mango",  y: 30  },
                { label: "grape",  y: 28  }
            ];
$scope.chart1.render();
```

Here is working demo:

<kbd>[Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kl6gNgOT8sqzLdFJASBd?p=preview)</kbd>

**Code**

```
var app = angular.module('myapp',[ ]);

  app.controller('HelloWorldController', function($scope, $http){

     var res = $http.get('http://localhost:8088/api/user/');
    res.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // your code 
    });
    res.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

          // fore testing I just use error callback to render async  
          $scope.options.data[0].dataPoints  = [
                { label: "apple",  y: 10  },
                { label: "orange", y: 15  },
                { label: "banana", y: 25  },
                { label: "mango",  y: 30  },
                { label: "grape",  y: 28  }
            ];

            $scope.chart1.render(); 
    }); 
    $scope.s=  [
      {"y":1,"legendText":"DB check","label":"DB","color":"green"},
      {"y":1,"legendText":"F  check","label":"Folder","color":"red"}];

   $scope.options =  {
                title:{
                    text: "Statistics of health check "
                },
                        animationEnabled: true,
                legend:{
                    verticalAlign: "center",
                    horizontalAlign: "left",
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontFamily: "Helvetica"        
                },
                theme: "theme2",
                data: [
                {        
                    type: "pie",       
                    indexLabelFontFamily: "Garamond",       
                    indexLabelFontSize: 20,

                    indexLabel: "{label} {y}%",
                    startAngle:-20,      
                    showInLegend: true,
                    toolTipContent:"{legendText} {y}%",
                    dataPoints:[] 
                }
                ]
            };

    $scope.chart1 = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",$scope.options);

              $scope.chart1.render();  


     });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer...but I think problem is in response data...its printing undefined when i use console.log but when i use {{myData}} its printing exact form i want

Comment: please post JSON you get in `success`. You should write something like `$scope.options.data[0].dataPoints = data;`  And don't forget to call `$scope.chart1.render(); ` after

Comment: Yes I've done same thing...for console.log($scope.options.data[0].dataPoints) its printing [ ] and for {{options.data[0].dataPoints}} its printing the exact value as in $scope.s

Comment: Json response  is  [  {"y":1,"legendText":"DB check","label":"DB","color":"green"},
      {"y":1,"legendText":"F  check","label":"Folder","color":"red"}]

Comment: Its working fine with static data problem here is to pass response data....console.log(data) is printing the required value...only when it is passed to other variable its passing undefined - @MaximShoustin

Comment: @rahul please take my demo, change it that shows your issue you are talking about, post link here  and I'll look on it